# onLocationChanged method does not work in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to get the user location and show it with a marker on the map but the method **onLocationChanged** does not work .. The Location can only be set manually i mean that i must set the longitude and latitude to an assigned value and it can't get it from the user location

here are the logcat screens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkqsU.jpg

and here is my code

```
package com.example.user.maps1
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Build
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready         to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    getPermission()
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
}

var accessCode = 222
fun getPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) , accessCode)
            return
        }
        getUserLocation()
    }

}

fun getUserLocation(){

    var myLocation = mylocationListener()

    var locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager


    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3, 3f, myLocation)
    }


    var mythread=myThread()
    mythread.start()


}
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {

    when(requestCode){

        accessCode->{

            if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getUserLocation()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"We cannot access to your location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}

var location:Location?=null
inner class mylocationListener: LocationListener {

    constructor(){
        location= Location("Start")
        //location!!.longitude=0.0
        //location!!.latitude=0.0
    }
    override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location?) {
        location=p0
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(p0: String?, p1: Int, p2: Bundle?) {
        //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onProviderEnabled(p0: String?) {
        // TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onProviderDisabled(p0: String?) {
        //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
inner class myThread:Thread{

    constructor():super(){}

    override fun run(){

            try {
                runOnUiThread {

                    mMap!!.clear()

                    // show me
                    val sydney = LatLng(location!!.latitude/*55.7558*/, location!!.longitude/*37.6173*/)
                    mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                            .position(sydney)
                            .title("Hello WOOORLD")
                            .snippet(" here is my location")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mario)))
                    mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 12f))

                }

                Thread.sleep(10000)

            }catch (ex:Exception){
                Log.e("00000000000000",ex.message.toString())
                //println(ex.message.toString())
            }


    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below class if you need location one time. You just need to call it like this

```
SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(context, this);
```

Class

```
public class SingleShotLocationProvider {
public static interface LocationCallback {
    public void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location);
}

// calls back to calling thread, note this is for low grain: if you want higher precision, swap the
// contents of the else and if. Also be sure to check gps permission/settings are allowed.
// call usually takes <10ms
public static void requestSingleUpdate(final Context context, final LocationCallback callback) {
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        }, null);
    } else {
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }

                @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
                @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
                @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
            }, null);
        }
    }
}


// consider returning Location instead of this dummy wrapper class
public static class GPSCoordinates {
    public float longitude = -1;
    public float latitude = -1;

    public GPSCoordinates(float theLatitude, float theLongitude) {
        longitude = theLongitude;
        latitude = theLatitude;
    }

    public GPSCoordinates(double theLatitude, double theLongitude) {
        longitude = (float) theLongitude;
        latitude = (float) theLatitude;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what should i type instead of "this" here because it says "Type mismatch"                 
                        
                        SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(context, this);

Comment: you just need to implement SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback on your calling activity

Comment: it says "Please specify constructor invocation;classifier LocationCallBack does not have a companion object

Comment: in your class  `class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback`

Comment: it says There is a circle in the inheritance hierarchy for this type

Comment: use `SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback` instead of `MapActivity.SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback`

Comment: It does not work                                                       
http://imgur.com/a/mAc4H

Comment: try only LocationCallback instead of SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback and if needed import the SingleShotLocationProvider class

Answer (score 0):

I did it but with another way

This tutorial was very helpful : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API